# How can you identify whether the language is regular or context-free language

Tags: dfa, formal-languages

For example, is this language regular or context-free language?
On the one hand `n` can't be smaller than `m` but on the other hand you can't count `n` and `m`.

> {(ab)^n (ab)^m | n>=m>=0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a trick question, as that's just `{(ab)^n | n>=0}` written in a obscure way. Which is clearly regular.

In general, you prove that a language *is* or *isn't* of a certain type with a grammar, automaton, pumping lemma, the Myhill–Nerode theorem, etc.